# If an airplane is flying sideways, is it in free fall?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft

If a plane turns 90 degrees such that it is flying sideways, is it accelerating towards the earth at the usual 9.8 m/s^2?

My guess is that the plane must be in free fall because I don't see what force is counteracting gravity.

Comment: Every shape generates both drag and lift. As long as there is enough engine power a plane can, in principle, fly sideways. Not many planes are designed for that kind of modus operandi, with exception of very agile fighter planes and some aerobatics machines. Having said that, there is a whole category of model planes that can do this trick just fine. See 3d aerobatics rc flight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkEPMooQpwY

Comment: Your question is not precise enough yet. Are the wings still horizontal (i.e. around which axis do you turn 90°)? *Sustained* sideways flying with horizontal wings is not possible. With vertical wings some planes have enough power to use the rudder to generate enough lift for sustained flight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with such a maneuver is that you're kicking in some strong g-forces there. Once you you hit an angle of 60$^\circ$ (the common banking angle for a commercial airliner), you are hitting 2G's. Past that, it goes exponentially:
[image]
([source](http://avstop.com/ac/flighttrainghandbook/loadfactorsinsteepturns.html)--load factor is the hypotenuse to gravitational & centrifugal forces. Note that the typical person can only handle about 5 G's, so less than 90$^\circ$ bank.)

The above chart assumes that the bank is at a constant altitude. What it shows is that the plane cannot actually fly at a 90$^\circ$ bank at a constant altitude, it must either incline or decline.

The [barrel roll maneuver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_roll) (source for image as well) turns the plane both longitudinally and laterally, while at two points the wings are banked at 90$^\circ$.
[image]

Since this maneuver can be done, it suggests that the plane would not experience free-fall while banked at 90$^\circ$, or else it would not be able to make the climb upwards.

Comment: See my comment above for a demonstration that in theory your answer is correct, but in practice it is wrong. The body of a suitably robust plane can generate all the lift needed to carry the wings as cargo, if the engine is just powerful enough. Heck, if the engine is powerful enough, the plane can stand still in the air or climb vertically, and no laws of nature are being violated. In general, there don't seem to be any technical limitations for 3d flight in Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: The OP wanted to know if the plane can rotate 90° and still fly (straight), not if it can bank at 90° for a turn.

Comment: That's the choice of the plane's operator. At the end of the video that thing hovers like a helicopter above the ground because the engine can generate far more propelling force than the machine weighs. The conventional theory of flight applies to conventional planes that generate much more lift with their wings than they can generate with their body or the props. None of that is of any importance for vastly over-powered aerobatics planes.

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from moving people in this contraption. Nothing stops you from moving people in a helicopter or a rocket. To physics it's all the same. Is there a reasonable question in here? I don't think so, unless we ask for the actual safe flight envelope of a specific plane design. Can a Piper or a 747 do this? No, at least not more than once. But in general there are no limitations, if the dominant force is the propelling force of the engine.

Comment: The g-force for turning is not exponential, it is [1/cos(alpha)](http://www.recreationalflying.com/tutorials/safety/turnback.html#procedure), alpha being the bank angle. You are describing a normal flight regime, whereas the OP seems to talk about flying sideways.

Comment: @YvesKlett: I am using *exponential* liberally here, signifying that the value increases at an incredible rate. Since the wheels are located on the *bottom* of the plane, you *must* start off in normal flight regime in order to *turn* sideways to fly that way.

Comment: If the barrel roll can be done, it wouldn't necessarily rule out free fall at 90 degrees, since it will only be at 90 degrees for a moment. Thanks for the info on g forces. I hadn't even considered it. I'm curious though just conceptually whether the plane would be falling. For example, would a pilot-less aircraft flying sideways start falling towards the earth?

Comment: @VivekViswanathan: As long as the propellers can generate enough thrust (as CuriousOne points out above), I don't see why a pilot-less airplane flying sideways would begin to fall.

Comment: @KyleKanos, So let's take wings and propellers separately. And I may easily be mistaken on any number of these points so feel free to correct me. Imagine we are flying with wings and suddenly the propellers fail. If the wings are at a 0 degree bank, then we would expect the horizontal velocity to allow the plane to glide for some period of time as the wings are still generating lift. Imagine we are  flying again at 0 degrees with functioning propellers but the wings fall off. Then, we plummet to the ground even if we have propellers. But if we fly at 90 degrees, even if we have propellers...

Comment: ...we do not have a source of lift. So I imagine we are falling. Is this rationale incorrect? If so, why?

Comment: @VivekViswanathan: Well, there's still the rudder capable of giving it some lift. Obviously not nearly as capable as the wings, but could provide some thrust.

Comment: @Vivek: There's a maneuver called a [*knife edge*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vm9hKP-e6U) where the wings are at 90 degrees to the ground. What the rudder does is put the fuselage sideways to the wind, generating the lift that holds the aircraft against gravity. Generally any such use of the rudder is called a *slip* or *skid*.

Answer (score 0):

Forget gravity for a little while, and put yourself in the pilot seat of an aerobatic airplane.

The plane has so-called "elevators" at the tail or "empenage", and those are connected to the stick that you hold.

What the elevators do is determine your angle of attack - the angle at which your wing meets the air stream.
If you pull back, the elevators move up, pushing the tail down, increasing your angle of attack.
This increases your lift, causing you to accelerate up in whatever direction "up" happens to be.

If you push the stick forward, that means less angle of attack, which means less lift.
If you push it far enough, you get zero lift - "free fall" if you want to call it that.
Push it even farther, and you get negative lift.
If you're flying inverted in a straight line, this is what you have to do.

Now put gravity back in the picture.
It is just another force acting on the airplane, that's all.
As I said, for continuous inverted flight, you need to push the stick forward to get -1g of vertical acceleration, to counter gravity.

You're hanging by your seat belt, which is why you keep it tight.

By the way, if you do a barrel roll, g-forces are positive throughout.
Even though the plane goes upside-down, it is never at 0 or negative G.
You can hold a cup of coffee through the whole maneuver.

Comment: Doesn't it only generate lift along the up down axis relative to the wings? That is, if the plane were flying with a 90 degree tilt laterally (let's say left wing pointed at the ground and the right at the sky), wouldn't pushing the stick forward and back only point the plane right and left respectively?

Comment: @Vivek: Yes, but would you call it free-fall? The pilot could be pulling 4G or more in that horizontal direction.